# bug using golang io.pipe to tar files

Tags: go, pipe, tar, gunzip

I have been testing code using io.Pipe to tar and gunzip files into a tar ball and then unzipping using the tar utility. The follow code passes, however the untaring process keeps getting

error:
`tar: Truncated input file (needed 1050624 bytes, only 0 available)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.`

This issue is really driving me crazy. It has been two weeks. I really need help debugging.

Thanks.

Development enviroment: go version go1.9 darwin/amd64

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "testing"
)

func testTarGzipPipe2(t *testing.T) {
    src := "/path/to/file/folder"

    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    gzipWriter := gzip.NewWriter(pw)
    defer gzipWriter.Close()
    tarWriter := tar.NewWriter(gzipWriter)
    defer tarWriter.Close()

    status := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        defer pr.Close()
        // tar to local disk
        tarFile, err := os.OpenFile("/path/to/tar/ball/test.tar.gz", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0755)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer tarFile.Close()
        if _, err := io.Copy(tarFile, pr); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        status <- true
    }()

    err := filepath.Walk(src, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(info, info.Name())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // header.Name = strings.TrimPrefix(strings.Replace(path, src, "", -1), string(filepath.Separator))

        if err := tarWriter.WriteHeader(header); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.Mode().IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        fmt.Println(path)
        f, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer f.Close()

        if _, err := io.Copy(tarWriter, f); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    pw.Close()
    <-status
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Also please `go fmt` the file

Comment: Unrelated: You shouldn't call log.Fatal in tests (or anywhere you expect to execute a `defer`statement), as it prevents any cleanup that you may intend to do, and can hide failing tests. There's a `t.Fatal` which does what you want. A tar file should not be executable. Close a channel rather than sending a sentinel value as a signal, or better yet, use a `WaitGroup` to wait for goroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the pipe before the deferred Close calls on the `gzipWriter` and `tarWriter`. There's no error, because you're not checking the error on either of those close calls. You need to close the `tarWriter`, then the `gzipWriter`, then the `PipeWriter`, in that order.

However, there's no reason for the pipe at all in this code, and you can remove the goroutine and the associated coordination altogether if you write directly to the file.

```
tarFile, err := os.OpenFile("/tmp/test.tar.gz", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer tarFile.Close()

gzipWriter := gzip.NewWriter(tarFile)
defer gzipWriter.Close()
tarWriter := tar.NewWriter(gzipWriter)
defer tarWriter.Close()
```

Comment: One important thing that I forgot is to close opened writer in reverse order. Hope others could learn from my mistake. Thanks again @ JimB.

Comment: @NSTNF: actually you had the `tarWriter.Close()` and `gzipWriter.Close()` correct, the defer calls are executed in LIFO order.

Comment: Thanks. Golang is different from other langs. It requires developer to change coding mind set. I am striving to code correctly and then efficiently.  Opened writers need to be closed in reverse order. This might be a common mistake. Would it be beneficial to other developers if creating a common mistakes wiki or add something like "warning: close tar writer before closing gzip writer" to the corresponding golang documentation?